# How to save sessions in Laravel 8

Tags: php, session, laravel-8

I am using Laravel 8, and I have been having problems with sessions. On the data page, I display the session variable `temperature`, but when I go to the main page and return back, the session is deleted. Maybe someone knows what the problem is? If I refresh the page, all is okay.

**Controller**

```php
public function set(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->put([
        'temperature' => $request->Temperature,
        'pressure' => $request->Pressure,
        'speed' => $request->Speed,
        'precipitation' => $request->Precipitation,
    ]);

    return view('settings');
}
```

**View**

```php
<select class="p-1 rounded-2" name="Temperature">
    <option value="temp_c">Celsius</option>
    <option value="temp_f" {{ session('temperature') == 'temp_f' ? 'selected':''}}>
        Fahrenheit
    </option>
</select>
```

**config/session**

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not use the session for this purpose. Pass variables to the view using the `with()` method. E.g.:

```php
public function settings(Request $request)
{
    $data = [
        'temperature' => $request->Temperature,
        'pressure' => $request->Pressure,
        'speed' => $request->Speed,
        'precipitation' => $request->Precipitation,
    ];

    return view('settings')->with($data);
}
```

And then in your view:

```html
<select class="p-1 rounded-2" name="Temperature">
    <option value="temp_c" {{ $temperature === 'temp_c' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Celsius</option>
    <option value="temp_f" {{ $temperature === 'temp_f' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Fahrenheit</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Session` facade for putting data in session:

```
\Session::put([
    'temperature' => $request->Temperature,
    'pressure' => $request->Pressure,
    'speed' => $request->Speed,
    'precipitation' => $request->Precipitation,
]);
```

If you want to retrieve and delete the data from session by one method use `pull` method on `Session` facade as said [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#retrieving-deleting-an-item)

Comment: still doesn't work, if a refresh page all is okey,but when i switch to main page and come back the session is deleted